# Showing that $\frac{f(x)-f(x-h)}{h} \le f'(x) \le \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$ given that f' is increasing

Tags: calculus

We are considering that $h > 0$. I just don't really know how to approach this question; it seems that by taking the limit of the inequality as h goes to 0, each part of the inequality is going to be equal to $f'$, but I don't really understand why the fact that $f'$ is increasing is relevant to finding a solution to this question (and how to answer the question based on that constraint).

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

Use [The mean value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem) on $[x-h, x]$ and $[x, x+h]$ intervals

Answer (score 1):

The assumption is the $f'$ is an increasing function on $[x-h,x+h]$.

Now by the mean value theorem, there exist numbers $\xi_1\in (x-h,x)$ and $\xi_2 \in (x,x+h)$ such that

$$f'(\xi_1)=\frac{f(x)-f(x-h)}{h}$$

$$f'(\xi_2)=\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$

Inasmuch as $f'$ is increasing and $\xi_2>x>\xi_1$, we have

$$\frac{f(x)-f(x-h)}{h}=f'(\xi_1)\le f'(x)\le f'(\xi_2)= \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} \tag 1$$

as was to be shown!

Comment: Please let me know how to improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.  -Mark